# How can i include google map on my account detail page. It would be helpful if the code is also provided

Tags: visualforce

I am trying the visualforce page given in the recruiting app. But its not working.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide more detail around your questions and perhaps some of your code.

Comment: Heena, you'd help us by editing your question and including the code you've written so far, and explaning to us why "its not working". Without such details we can only guess at how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a visualforce Page named as Google map and than edit account layout, and add this visualforce page on account layout.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  }

  var map;
  var marker;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "{!Account.BillingStreet}, " + "{!Account.BillingCity}, " + "{!Account.BillingPostalCode}, " + "{!Account.BillingCountry}";

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>{!Account.Name}</b><br>{!Account.BillingStreet}<br>{!Account.BillingCity}, {!Account.BillingPostalCode}<br>{!Account.BillingCountry}"
  });

  geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

        //create map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        //center map
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        //create marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: "{!Account.Name}"
        });

        //add listeners
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); 
        });

      }

    } else {
      $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
      $('#map').html("Oops! {!Account.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
      resizeIframe();
    }
  });

  function resizeIframe() {
    var me = window.name;
    if (me) {
      var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
      if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
        height = document.body.offsetHeight;
        iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }
  }

});
</script>

<style>
#map {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
  height:250px;
  background:transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
</body> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can uses the visualforce component apex:map. That you have an example

```
<apex:map width="600px" height="400px" mapType="roadmap" center="{!Account.BillingStreet},{!Account.BillingCity},{!Account.BillingState}">
                <apex:repeat value="{! Account.Contacts }" var="contact">
                <apex:mapMarker title="{! contact.Name }" position="{!contact.MailingStreet},{!contact.MailingCity},{!contact.MailingState}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:map>
```

Best Regards